# Should I deseasonalize my time series before using SARIMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, seasonality, trend

I have the following time-series that I need to model using SARIMA. There is a clear seasonality pattern but there is no apparent trend.

Should I de-seasonalize (seasonal differencing) my time series before applying SARIMA?

[image: GDP Growth Rate]

Comment: If you are happy with my answers please accept them to bring notoriety.

Answer (score 2):

no .. because seasonal structure is the S in SARIMA . If you post an example of your data I may be able to help further